# Call Python cProfile from within a function. (Or other way to use cProfile with Django)

Tags: python, cprofile

How do I call cProfile from within a function, using it to call and profile another function?

I have a function start(), which is called from my webpage (using Django). In this function I place the cProfile call:

```
cProfile.run('my_function()')
```

This gives me the error "Name my_function is not defined". However, the function is called no problem if I just do a normal function call: my_function()

Everything says to execute the "main" function using cProfile, but I don't really have a single main function or an obvious way to run my program except from the webpage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need `runctx` instead of `run`.

You can pass globals and locals to the `cProfile.runctx` call, like this:

```
cProfile.runctx('my_function()', globals=globals(), locals=locals())
```